# how to update a property from ViewController in my another class(SWIFT)

Tags: ios, swift, nsnotificationcenter

I searched but only see OC version and seems should use NSNotificationCenter?

In ViewController class viewDidLoad func there is a textField, please see below:

```
     class ViewController: UIViewController {
        var textField1 = UITextField()
        override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        textField1.frame = CGRectMake(20, 70, 300, 500)
        textField1.text = "Default"        
        self.view.addSubview(textField1)
```

In another class ContactData there is a func getContacts which will be called in ViewController, in this func I need update textField1 texts property, when use ViewController.textField1.text = "XXXXXX" below don't works, I am new on IOS SWIFT, could anyone can help me to solve this problem?

```
class ContactData: NSObject {    
    func getContacts()
{ViewController.textField1.text = "XXXXXX"}
```

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is more a problem of design here. Your function `getContacts` should not update the text field directly. It should return the contact string, and the view controller should call this method to get the string and update the text field.

```
class ContactData: NSObject {    
    func getContacts() -> String
    {
         return "XXXXXX"
    }
}
```

In your UIViewController:

```
let myContact = ContactData()
textField1.text = myContact.getContacts()
```

Comment: Thank you, this is good solution, but if I need update more than one texts property, for example I also need update a button texts in ContactData Class, then how to deal with this?

Comment: It is very hard to answer without context and more explanation. If you need different information that are coming from the ContactData class, you can implement several functions (e.g. getContact, getAddress, getTelephone), and use those function inside your view controller the same way I explain for getContact. As those function will return a string, you will be able to use them to change the text on a button, text field or other UI objects.